# nhibernate linq basics

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I need to transform this query to nhibernate linq

```
 IEnumerable<Account> accounts = from a in dc.Accounts
                                 where (a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName).Contains(SearchText) ||
                                        a.Email.Contains(SearchText) ||
                                        a.Username.Contains(SearchText)
                                 select a;
```

I tried with this but I"m stuck at the beginning so I need help.

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts = NHSession.Query<Account>().Where(x=>x.FirstName)
```

Comment: 'I need help' is not a question. If you asked a specific question you would get much more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query below will return `IQueryable<Account>` , you can either use it for further querying or evaluate to obtain results.

```
var accounts = NHSession.Query<Account>().Where(a=> (a.FirstName+" "+a.LastName).Contains(SearchText) || a.Email.Contains(SearchText) || a.Username.Contains(SearchText) );
```

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your query you might want to spend a few min and read Ayende's post on Complex Searching found [here](http://ayende.com/blog/1900/complex-searching-querying-with-nhibernate).

Rather than using the Session Query or Detached Criteria - look into implementing this as a QueryOver.  Then you can build the search criteria well ahead of the session call, then simply pass in the query to the session when you are finally ready to bring it up. Also don't forget [Future Values](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures) and Paging for larger result sets: